# new Symfony project on apache server needs mod_rewrite code?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, apache2, front-controller

I have just created a new (test) symfony project and set my apache webroot to `/home/user/project/` (not sure if it should be `/home/user/project/web/`?)

However, from what I understand based on the lightbulb section here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#the-web-directory - there isn't any internal rerouting occurring. Therefore, this does not work:

```
http://localhost/random/10
```

but these do work:

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/random/10
http://localhost/app.php/random/10
```

To double check, if I start the internal PHP server (`php app/console server:start`) then everything gets rerouted correctly - this does work:

```
http://localhost:8000/random/10
```

Am I right in thinking that I need to make changes to .htaccess? If so, is there a 'standard' section of code for using apache with symfony?

EDIT:
I have updated my `apache2.conf` (which for others would be `httpd.conf` if not on ubuntu as I understand it) as below:

```
<Directory /home/user/Project/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `.htaccess` alredy defines `DirectoryIndex` as `app.php`. However, your Apache config file `httpd.conf` might be blocking the override.

Make sure that you have that line in your `.htaccess` and also check the value of `AllowOverride` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)) within your `httpd.conf`. Try setting `AllowOverride` to `All` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks @JovanPerovic - yes my .htaccess has `DirectoryIndex app.php`. Regarding `httpd.conf`, I'm on Ubuntu so I just have `apache2.conf` as far as I understand. However, after making the change you suggested the problem still exists. I will update my question now to include the change I've made to apache2.conf in case I've done it wrong

Comment: Ah, in case of an Ubuntu, that is where you need to look. I assume you did restart your Apache service afterwards, right? Also, can you confirm that mod_rewrite has indeed been enabled in your Apache? I think `apache2ctl -M` can give the answer...

Comment: I had forgotten to restart the apache server...! Works perfectly now :) Thanks for solving it Jovan